# In ASP.Net Core 5 MVC Controller, when passed a JSON object FromBody that contains a decimal the model is always null

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, .net-core, model-binding

Passing in this json works:

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "barcode": "1",
      "quantity": 1,
      "name": "Barratt Fruit Salad Chews 400 pc box",
      "unitPrice": 8,
      "totalPrice": 8,
      "isInBuyTwoGetOneFreePromotion": false
    }
  ]
}
```

Passing in this json does not work:

```json
{
  "products": [
    {
      "barcode": "8",
      "quantity": "4",
      "name": "Bonds dinosaurs",
      "unitPrice": 0.5,
      "totalPrice": 2,
      "isInBuyTwoGetOneFreePromotion": true
    }
  ]
}
```

The reason is the decimal being passed.

My controller has this method

```cs
[HttpPost]
        public async Task<JsonResult> UpdateStockAndLogInvoice([FromBody] Invoice invoice)
```

It references this model:

```cs
public partial class Invoice
    {
        [JsonProperty("products")]
        public List<InvoiceItem> Products { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class InvoiceItem
    {
        [JsonProperty("barcode")]
        public string Barcode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("name")]
        public string Name { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("quantity")]
        public int Quantity { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("totalPrice")]
        public long TotalPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("unitPrice")]
        public long UnitPrice { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isInBuyTwoGetOneFreePromotion")]
        public bool IsInBuyTwoGetOneFreePromotion { get; set; }
    }
```

I believe the issue is in converting from the float used in javascript to the long used in C#, but I have scoured the internet and cannot work out how to get my model being passed in to not be null.

Any suggestions gratefully accepted!

Comment: Any reason you can't change your model to accept `decimal`? Your usage vs. your model suggests you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your failed JSON is not compatible with your `InvoiceItem` class in at least two ways:

- `Quantity` is not a string.
- `UnitPrice` is a long, it can't accept floating point values.

During request processing the MVC model binder attempts to deserialize the JSON body into the requested `InvoiceItem` type and fails. It treats this failure as if the body was empty, checks whether you've told it to allow empty bodies (which it does by default) and continues on as if no body had been supplied.

To fix this you need to resolve the difference between your client side and server side models. Since JavaScript really doesn't care about types you have to be particularly careful to ensure that you are managing the client side data correctly, otherwise it's not going to deserialize correctly on the server side. Different ASP.NET MVC versions may have different restrictions when it comes to the translations it will handle automatically, but valid JSON that matches your model will always work.

So... update your server side model to use decimal for the `UnitPrice` and `TotalPrice` properties, then fix your client side javascript to put the right value types in.

Comment: It turns out that I had no reason to use long here, so changing to decimal did the trick. I'm not sure why sometimes that quantity is output to json console as a string, it's never actually done that when sent over to the API, so should be fine as-is. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @jcreek "I'm not sure why..." and that's a problem. If some portion of the code you're using can get the type wrong under certain circumstances then at some point it may break your system - probably at a critical moment. I'd advise finding out what's happening and fix it before it bites you.